# How does iTunes determine how to stack tracks, and why aren't these?

Tags: itunes

Note that this album is not grouping together for some reason - even though only one artist & album appear in the browser. I've got a few that sit like this. How do I fix it?

[image: Screenshot of iTunes]

<sup>Click image for full size</sup>

Comment: Could you clarify what you want the album to do, maybe show a picture of a non-grouped one? As far as I can tell that screenshot looks correct so I must be misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3):

Right-click some of these tracks and get the `Get Info` window.
In particular check the options outlined in the images below, chances are the files have some unexpected meta data attached here that iTunes is using to sort them in an unexpected manner.

[image: iTunes song "get info" window; "Info" tab with "Album Artist" and "Grouping" highlighted]

[image: iTunes song "get info" window; "Sorting" tab with all "Sort ..." fields highlighted]

Comment: I looked at each tab for each track, and the only fields that ever differed were title and track number.

Comment: Darn.... Hmm, are all the files in the same folder on your HD? Not sure if that matters, but it jumps to mind. Also,might be worth trying to set some of the above options, to see if that forces the grouping.